# Check whether RVM is properly loaded or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I have been working on the issue where I need to find whether:
1. RVM is properly installed on the system or not.
   I am checking the existence of `$HOME/.rvm` directory for doing so. If it exists then RVM is successfully installed else not.
Kindly mention if I am doing something wrong or if there's any better way of doing the same.

2.RVM is properly installed but is not properly loaded.
   I was wondering if the output of `rvm -v` or `type rvm` can be used for the same.
I am not entirely sure which attribute to use. Any idea on it?